# Return category group with salesforce knowledge articles

Tags: knowledge, sosl, data-category

I' writing one sosl query, where I'm facing problem while returning category group.

```
FIND {tourism} RETURNING KnowledgeArticleVersion
    (Id, Title WHERE PublishStatus='draft')
    WITH DATA CATEGORY Geography__c BELOW Europe__c
```

So here with my KnowledgeArticleVersion data I also wanted to display Europe__c because all these knowledge articels are below Europe__c.
How can I display the category?